# How to avoid SQL injection risk when creating table dynamically?

Tags: mysql, sql-injection

Here is simple procedure that creates table from user provided input:

```
PROCEDURE `hackProcedure`(
IN tab_name VARCHAR(63))
BEGIN

IF (tab_name REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$')
THEN
    SET @StB = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE tab_name
                      (id INT(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
                      name VARCHAR(45),
                      guid VARCHAR(36));');
    PREPARE statementB FROM @StB;
    EXECUTE statementB;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE statementB;
ELSE
    -- SIGNAL some error;
END IF;
#END
```

Before creating table I check that user input contains only alfa-numeric values, so to my understanding bad person trying to do an SQL injection on this procedure can not succeed because it is not possible to comment out the rest of the query nor add other columns. Is this safe or I am missing someting?

Comment: Allowing users (non-DBA, non-developer, generally untrusted users) to create tables in the first place is a bit strange.  What's the use case here?

Comment: Agreed, why would a user have any control over the schema?

Comment: Also, to prevent SQL injection, you have to use prepared statements no matter the case, it is no different if you are allowing users to create tables. Just use prepared statements

Comment: @David Yes, I know, but that is a requirement here. To minimize risk, users will only have access to executing stored procedures.

Comment: @window Table names can't be replaced as values in prepared statements though.

Comment: I knew this somewhere but couldn't recall,@deceze looks like the user has to provide us the language in which he is using MySQL, so we can further help him

Comment: @deceze - if you look at previous question that OP made, Raymond made a comment that shows how a prepared statement can be used to create a table whose name comes from user input. The solution isn't foolproof though. However, you're right, using the parameter *directly* in the statement won't work. I also second everyone who asked why would a user be responsible for schema change. This appears to be an XY problem.

Comment: "Also, to prevent SQL injection, you have to use prepared statements" - no prepared statements (mostly) prevent SQLi, but it's not the only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not vulnerable because the code you've shown us uses a literal value for the table name - not the parameter. I think you wanted to do this:

```
CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ',  tab_name, '
                  (id INT(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  name VARCHAR(45),
                  guid VARCHAR(36));');
```

Now, what if I call your function with...

```
dummy (id INT NOT NULL); DROP TABLE mysql.users; CREATE TABLE dummy2
```

?

It will fail because the semi-colon and brackets wull be rejected by the regex, but this is far from a robust solution.

Adding backtick quotes around the table name (as long as they are disallowed by the regex) is a slight improvement.

```
 CONCAT('CREATE TABLE `',  tab_name, '`
```

Comment: +1 Also the back-ticks are necessary because the regexp allows a space, and does not prevent the table name from being a reserved SQL keyword.

Comment: @Bill Karwin. Thank you for your suggestions!